# Replace Window's Background with shadowed Image

Tags: wpf

I'm looking to replace my solid color background of my window to be an image with a drop shadow.. how can i achieve such thing?

I tried to make the BG transparent and even to null but it didn't show the inside elements..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use the [`ImageBrush` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This is like a standard `Brush`, but it *Paints an area with an image* instead:

```
<Window ... >
    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush Viewport="0,0,0.5,0.5" TileMode="FlipXY"
            ImageSource="/YourAppName;component/ImageFolderName/ImageName.png" />
    </Window.Background>
<Window>
```

You can experiment with the `TileMode` and `Viewport` settings to get different effects. Please see the linked page from MSDN for more details.

Comment: it works fine but when u try to import the image from the resources
`pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/startup.png`
it says
`'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '6' and line position '21'.`

Comment: Maybe try it *like I showed you*: `ImageSource="/YourAppName;component/Resources/startup.png"`, or did you get it working in the end?

Comment: yes i did try it but still.. it only works with a direct path like `C:\image.png` weird

Comment: Maybe you can find an answer to this issue in the [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN?